# Is it possible to boot Raspberry Pi 4 model B from USB without touching SD cards at all? [Broken SD card slot]

Tags: usb, boot, sd-card

My SD card slot broke off (as in only pins are left and I would have to hold down an SD card for it to boot). [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okfrs.jpg)

I've written Raspberry Pi OS to a USB drive, I was told the Raspberry Pi 4 B could boot from USB without modification, clearly that was not accurate. when I boot the rpi4b it tries to boot from the SD card multiple times.

```
SD card not detected
SD CMD: 0x371a0010 (55) 0x0 0x1fff0001
Failed to open device: 'sdcard'
^ repeats 2 more times
SD card not detected
SD boot failed
BOOT_STOPPED: 0x00000001 0x0
```

then it shuts off after a minute or two.

I don't even own an SD card or soldering kit currently and cant even find the SD card slot that broke off.

Comment: `raspberry pi 4b could boot from USB without modification` - guess it depends on the EEPROM when the pi was manufactured. I would assume that any pi 4 manufactured in the last couple of years would boot from USB, though I could be wrong of course.

Comment: @JaromandaX the year on my raspberry pi says 2018, and the bootloader version is a5e1b95f april 16 2020

Comment: What did you want me to do with that information?

Comment: USB Boot was added in **May 2020** - so, you're out of luck there - However, 16 April 2020 firmware  **supports network  boot** - so there's an option for you